# C# UWP if counter stays the same for a specific duration

Tags: c#, timer, uwp

How do I create a function where if a counter stays the same for 5 seconds, then something happens? From what I know, I have to assign a name to the old counter values then I compare it. IS this correct?

**My code consists of the timeout**

```
 if (x1 && y1 && z1)
 {
    txtAngle.Text = "";
    txtDisplay.Text = "Number of times: " + counter + "\n" + "Go back to start position and repeat the exercise for " + databaseValue + " times";
    txtAgain.Text = "Go back to starting position.";
    txtAgain1.Text = "";
    counter++;

 // assign the old counter value as previous counter

        if (counter == previousCounter) // If the counter never increase for 5 seconds
        {
            timeout.Tick += timeout_TickAsync;
            timeout.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
            timeout.Start();
        }
    timeangle1.Stop();
 }
```

**Timeout function**

```
private void timeout_TickAsync(object sender, object e)
{
  // something happens.
    txtClock.Text = "HELLO WORLD";
    timeout.Stop();
}
```

This code has an error because its incomplete and Idk how to continue from here. Someone, please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an asynchronous method to handle that.

```
void aync Task UpdateCounterAsync(int newValue)
{
    var oldValue = _counter;
    _counter = newValue;
    await Task.Delay(Timespan.FromSeconds(5));
    if (_counter == oldValue)
    {
        // counter is still the same; do something
    }
}
```

It will update a member variable named `_counter` wait for 5 seconds and check if the value available after the delay is still the same.

If you want to be more resilient, you can also track the task returned by `Task.Delay()` and cancel it each time you have a new update. You will need a `CancellationTokenSource` member variable say `_cancellationTokenSource`

```
void aync Task UpdateCounterAsync(int newValue)
{
    var oldValue = _counter;
    _counter = newValue;
    _cancellationSourceToken.Cancel();
    _cancellationSourceToken = new CancellationSourceToken();

    try
    {
        await Task.Delay(Timespan.FromSeconds(5), _cancellationSourceToken.Token);
        if (_counter == oldValue)
        {
            // counter is still the same; do something
        }
    }
    catch (TaskCancelledException)
    {
        // another update has been triggered while we were waiting. 
        // _counter has obviously changed then bail out
    }
}
```